# Symfony Swfitmailer SES error on 2nd email within 25 minutes

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer, amazon-ses

I have a piece of Symfony code that

- sends an email
- runs an SQL query that takes around 25 minutes
- sends another email

On the second email, I always get the following error message:

```
In AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 457:

  Expected response code 250 but got code "451", with message "451 4.4.2 Timeout waiting for data from client.  
  "
```

My code is as follows:

```
public function rebuild()
{
    $twig = clone $this->twig;

    /** @var Setting $setting */
    $setting = $this->em->getRepository(Setting::class)->find(1);

    $usersToNotify = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findBy([
        'notify_card_data_rebuild' => 1
    ]);
    $timetrack = microtime(true);

    foreach ($usersToNotify as $user) {
        /** @var $user User */
        $message = new \Swift_Message();
        $message
            ->setFrom('info@meezysolutions.com')
            ->setSubject($twig->createTemplate($setting->getCardDataRebuildStartEmailSubject())->render([
                'user' => $user
            ]))
            ->setTo($user->getEmail(), $user->getFirstname() . ' ' . $user->getLastname())
            ->setBody($twig->createTemplate($setting->getCardDataRebuildStartEmailMessage())->render([
                'user' => $user
            ]));
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }

...
$sql = '25 Minute query';

    $this->em->getConnection()->exec($sql);

    $endtime = microtime(true);
    foreach ($usersToNotify as $user) {
        /** @var $user User */
        $message = new \Swift_Message();
        $message
            ->setFrom('info@meezysolutions.com')
            ->setSubject($twig->createTemplate($setting->getCardDataRebuildCompleteEmailSubject())->render([
                'user' => $user
            ]))
            ->setTo($user->getEmail(), $user->getFirstname() . ' ' . $user->getLastname())
            ->setBody($twig->createTemplate($setting->getCardDataRebuildCompleteEmailMessage())->render([
                'user' => $user,
                'time_taken' => $endtime-$timetrack
            ]));
        $this->mailer->send($message);
    }
```

Swiftmailer configuration is as per below and MAILER_URL includes the SMTP details for AWS SES

bin/console debug:config SwiftmailerBundle

```
Current configuration for "SwiftmailerBundle"
=============================================

swiftmailer:
    default_mailer: default
    mailers:
    default:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    transport: smtp
    command: '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs'
    username: null
    password: null
    host: localhost
    port: null
    timeout: 30
    source_ip: null
    local_domain: null
    encryption: null
    auth_mode: null
    delivery_addresses: {  }
    logging: true
    delivery_whitelist: {  }
```

Does Swiftmailer keep the connection open to SES? If yes, how do I turn this off?

Comment: just to rule this out ... but do you receive the first mail? the `timeout` configuration setting should lead to a new smtp connection.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand all your process, but when I have so long request, I use the messenger component, then I update its configuration to be used as an async message.   With this method, your Swiftmailer won't stay open.

Comment: @jakumi yes, I am receiving the first email.

Comment: @AlexandreTranchant yes this code is already run that way. I have considered this as a solution as well, but I'm not in a super hurry, so I thought I get some "canonical" advice

Comment: Just try to update it. Seems it was fixed in this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/36301) few days ago

Comment: @EugeneRuban have upgraded to 5.0.7 and problem is still there. I have also looked at the ticket in more detail and it appears to apply to people who have between 10 and 100 seconds between email sending. I have at least 1500 seconds in between

Comment: @jdog so, the most canonical way here, imho, to move this big process to the background (with messenger component, in example), and to send the second mail by event on completing of the process.

Comment: @EugeneRuban yes I agree. that is the "best" solution and most practical solution. I'll just leave it here for anyone wanting to run a PHP script for a long time and send emails.